# Rebus with 20 song titles

Tags: wordplay, visual, rebus, language, music

> [image]

Guess the 20 song titles depicted above.

Comment: Haha they are all great but 19 is my favourite <3

Comment: This puzzle was the most fun one I've seen in a while! Nice job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**FULL ANSWER:**

1)

> Shop Around

2)

> Rock Around The Clock

3)

> Singin' In The Rain (@Omega Krypton)

4)

> Between The Sheets (@Omega Krypton)

5)

> A Day In The Life

6)

> Silver Threads Among the Gold (@Neil W)

7)

> Down by The River

8)

> Baby Got Back

9)

> Another Brick In The Wall

10)

> Say It Right (@Omega Krypton)

11)

> Born In USA (@Omega Krypton)

12)

> Higher Ground (@Omega Krypton)

13)

> Stand By Me (@Omega Krypton)

14)

> Back In Black

15)

> Love Struck Baby (@Neil W)

16)

> Norwegian Wood

17)

> Paint It Black

18)

> Boulevard of Broken Dreams

19)

> Brown Eyed Girl (@Neil W)

20)

> Here I Go Again

Comment: Ding ding ding...!

Answer (score 7):

Partial Answer

thanks to Ak19 and pirate for their contributions!

1)

> Shop Around

2)

> Rock Around The Clock

3)

> Singin' in the Rain

4)

> Between the sheets

5)

> A Day in the Life

6)

> Silver threads and Golden needles

7)

> Down by The River

8)

> Baby Got Back

9)

> Another Brick In The Wall

10)

> Say it Right

11

> Born in USA

12)

> Higher ground

13)

> Stand by Me

14)

> Back In Black

15)

> Love Struck Baby

17)

> So Blue It's Black

18)

> Boulevard of Broken Dreams

19)

> Girl with One Eye

20)

> Here I Go Again

Comment: 6, 17 and 19 are wrong, everything else's correct.

Answer (score 5):

5)

> A Day in the Life

6)

> Silver Threads Among the Gold

15)

> Love Struck Baby

19)

> Brown Eyed Girl

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer

2

> Rock around the clock

7

> Down the River ?

8

> Baby got back

11

> Born in USA

13

> Stand by me ?

14

> Back in Black